# Wordpress Reports on orders with discounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello i would like to make a report in the wp-admin a report showing the following details for orders that had discounts:
  [ order number, order date, order status, order total, user name, email and phone ]

WooCommerce Reports doesn't do that.

I found this code:

```
// 1. Create function that calculates sales based on coupon code

function bbloomer_get_sales_by_coupon($coupon_id) {
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_status' => ['wc-processing', 'wc-completed', 'wc-on-hold']
    ];
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $orders = $my_query->posts;
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($orders as $key => $value) {
        $order_id = $value->ID;
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $items = $order->get_items('coupon'); 

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            if( $item['code'] == $coupon_id ) {
                $total += $order->get_total();
            }
        }
    }
    return 'Total sales for coupon "' . $coupon_id . '": ' . wc_price($total);
}

// -------------------------

// 2. Add new tab to WooCommerce "Reports", and print the coupon total sales

add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_reports', 'bbloomer_add_report_tab' );
function bbloomer_add_report_tab( $reports ) {
    $reports['coupons'] = array(
        'title'  => __( 'Coupons', 'woocommerce' ),
        'reports' => array(
            "sales_by_code" => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Sales by code', 'woocommerce' ),
                'description' => bbloomer_get_sales_by_coupon('barmada'), //change coupon code here
                'hide_title'  => false,
                'callback'    => '',
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $reports;
}
```

It gets the number of sales by a coupon but instead I want to get the number of sales that had discounts on it and return the   [ order number, order date, order status, order total, user name, email and phone ]

Where should I start to achieve this task? Any track is appreciated.